# How to fetch multiple value from jsp to ArrayList in action

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I would like to send multiple data from jsp and want to fetch it in `ArrayList` in action 
But It is showing entire value as one element.

In Jsp

```
 <span class="label"> Item Name</span>
 <span class="ib"> <input type="text" name="item" id="item"/></span>
```

I am giving multiple value as input separated by comma

```
  funny,action,cartoon
```

In Action I would like to fetch in ArrayList

```
public class Test extends ActionSupport{

   private ArrayList item;
  //getter and setter of item
```

How to do this.

Comment: why dont you  get the string as is into action and split the string using `split(",")` and use the `Arrays.asList()` method?

Comment: Why not to use separate input elements for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying the following code

```
String value = "funny,action,cartoon";
String[] split = value.split(",");
List<String> sampleList = Arrays.asList(split);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Action` class needs to accept the items as a `String` but populate the `ArrayList` as

```
public class Test extends ActionSupport {

   private List<String> items;

  // getter/setter for items

  public void setItem(String item) {
    String[] items = item.split(",");
    this.items = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items));
  }

}
```

Notice, the difference between the names: `item` is `String`, `items` is a `List`.

Comment: This is also a great answer

Comment: @Manish Please note that by using `Arrays.asList()` directly your `List` becomes immutable i.e. you cannot add to or modify your list any more. Hence, I've used a *copy constructor* instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use JSTL `<c:forEach>` in your jsp to loop over array.